# Relation from master to details but not vice versa

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `Order` entity that has multiple `OrderItem` entities. and classes would look like that.

```
class Order
{
     int Id;
     string Note;
     List<OrderItem> OrderItems;
}

class OrderItem
{
     int Id;
     string Name;
}
```

as you can see, `Order` knows about its `OrderItems` and `OrderItem` doesn't know about its `Order`.

The question is how do I write a linq query to query the context for an `OrderItem` that belongs to a specific `order`?

Comment: I am pretty new to EF so I don't know a lot about the tool, but I was trying context.OrderItems.Where(x => x.Order.Id == 999) . but this is where I faced the problem, there is no property x.Order to feed into the query.

Comment: Normally you _would_ have an `OrderId` in you `OrderItem`. Why is it not there? Did you write those classes? If they were generated, I really wonder about your data model... If you wrote them, simple add the OrderId where it belongs. As it is now, you can only get all orderitems, never a single one, belonging to an order: Order.OrderItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would query for the correct `Order`, then select the related `OrderItem`(s), e.g:

```
var orderItems = context.Orders
                        .Where(o => o.Id == selectedId)
                        .Select(o => o.OrderItems)
                        .ToList();
```

This gives you the list of order items associated to the order with Id `selectedId`.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `Order` property in your `OrderItem` class. Also you should use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in your classes instead of fields like below:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that I used the `virtual` keyword and `ICollection` instead of `List` which makes the property supports lazy loading.

Answer (score 2):

`Context.Orders.Where(x => x.Id == 1234).SelectMany(x => x.OrderItems);`

or you could do `Context.Where(x => x.Id == 1234).Include(x => x.OrderItems)` to get the order and pre-load its items.

I recommend making the Order.OrderItems property virtual, so at least if ever you forget to pre-load (or `.Include`) then you won't get inconsistent data loaded from the DB.